# safe-core: deployProxyWithNonce using script

Tags: safe-core

I would like to call :
deployProxyWithNonce from https://etherscan.io/address/0xa6b71e26c5e0845f74c812102ca7114b6a896ab2#code, not using your UI but with tradictionnal scripts, how could i get saltNonce and how could i get initializer since for instance i need to have a 2 threshold on 5 addresses :

owners :
0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266
0x70997970C51812dc3A010C7d01b50e0d17dc79C8
0x3C44CdDdB6a900fa2b585dd299e03d12FA4293BC
0x90F79bf6EB2c4f870365E785982E1f101E93b906
0x15d34AAf54267DB7D7c367839AAf71A00a2C6A65
threshold :
2

Comment: Can you provide mores details? What are you trying to accomplish? Why do you need to call that contract? Did you try using the official SDK?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer.
Actually, I would like to use your smart contract to create multisigs on the fly, from a simple script. Do I have to go through your SDK, or is there another way

Comment: The question is not closed btw

Comment: I reopened the question. I think you don't need to use the SDK, but you will have to know how the contract interact between them.

Comment: Sorry i meant for Function: createProxyWithNonce(address _singleton, bytes initializer, uint256 saltNonce) how can i generate the nonce ?

Answer (score 0):

The contract you are trying to interact with is the [`SafeProxyFactory`](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/blob/main/contracts/proxies/SafeProxyFactory.sol) v.1.3.0. As you can see in the source code, the `saltNonce` is an arbitrary number you can choose to force the creation of a contract to a fixed address, used by `CREATE2` opcode. It is useful when you need to deploy multiple safes on multiple chains but on the same address each time. To do this, simply use the same `saltNonce` value for each one. You can choose any value you want.

You can read more on `CREATE2` [here](https://coinsbench.com/a-comprehensive-guide-to-the-create2-opcode-in-solidity-7c6d40e3f1af) or see the official specification [here](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1014).

Hope it helps,
Louis

Comment: I can see that the abi signature is 0xb63e800d, which is or should be something like this isn't it ? 
setup(address[],uint256,address,bytes,address,address,uint256,address)

is this good ?

Comment: So what about, if i use createProxy, the verification of the contract, is it done automatically since it is a proxy or not ?
@louis-safe-core-team